# Counting number of rows where a value occurs at least once within many columns

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I updated the question with pseudocode to better explain what I would like to do.

I have a data.frame named **df_sel**, with 5064 rows and 215 columns.

Some of the columns (~80) contains integers with a unique identifier for a specific trait (medications). These columns are named "meds_0_1", "meds_0_2", "meds_0_3" etc. as well as "meds_1_1", "meds_1_2", "meds_1_3". Each column may or may not contain any of the integer values I am looking for.

For the specific integer values to look for, some could be grouped under different types of medication, but coded for specific brand names.

```
metformin = 1140884600  # not grouped
sulfonylurea = c(1140874718, 1140874724, 1140874726) # grouped
```

If it would be possible to look-up a group of medications, like in a vector format as above, that would be helpful.

I would like to do this:

```
IF [a specific row] 
CONTAINS [the single integer value of interest] 
IN [any of the columns within the df starting with "meds_0"] 
A_NEW_VARIABLE_METFORMIN = 1 ELSE A_NEW_VARIABLE_METFORMIN = 0
```

and concordingly

```
IF [a specific row] 
CONTAINS [any of multiple integer values of interest] 
IN [any of the columns within the df starting with "meds_0"] 
A_NEW_VARIABLE_SULFONYLUREA = 1 ELSE A_NEW_VARIABLE_SULFONYLUREA = 0
```

---

I have manged to create a vector based on column names:

```
column_names <- names(df_sel) %>% str_subset('^meds_0')
```

But I havent gotten any further despite some suggestions below.

I hope you understand better what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the selection of the columns, you could do this by first extracting the names in the way you are doing with a regex, and then using `select`:

```
library(stringr)
column_names <- names(df_sel) %>% 
  str_subset('^meds_0')

relevant_df <- df_sel %>%
  select(column_names)
```

I didn't quite get the structure of your variables (if they are integers, logicals, etc.), so I'm not sure how to continue, but it would probably involve something like summing across all the columns and dropping those that are not 0, like:

```
meds_taken <- rowSums(relevant_df)
df_sel_med_count <- df_sel %>% 
  add_column(meds_taken)
```

At this point you should have your initial df with the relevant data in one column, and you can summarize by subject, medication or whatever in any way you want.

If this is not enough, please edit your question providing a relevant sample of your data (you can do this with the `dput` function) and I'll edit this answer to add more detail.

Comment: I appreciate your help! The regexp to get the **column_names** works perfect, all relevant columns extracted into a vector. However, when I build **relevant_df** using the code you provided, it gives me only one column (the first in **column_names**), with all rows.

Comment: It's because of a typo! Sorry. I typed `select_`, when it should have been `select`. I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: I tried, but the new variable created and added to the df does count the values, not the number of occurances. I update dmy question above to better explain my question.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to start off by recommending bioconductor for R libraries, as it sounds like you may be studying biological data. Now to your question.

Although tidyverse is the most widely acceptable and 'easy' method, I would recommend in this instance using 'lapply' as it is extremely fast. Your code from a programming standpoint becomes a simple boolean, as you stated, but I think we can go a little further. Using the built-in data from 'mtcars',

```
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars, 6)
target=6

#trues and falses for each row and column

rows=lapply(mtcars, function(x) x %in% target)

#Number of Trues for each column and which have more that 0 Trues

column_sums=unlist(lapply(rows, function(x) (sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))))
which(column_sums>0)
```

This will work with other data types with a few tweaks here and there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on Bioconductor, will check out. Your answer took me closer to my goal, please see edit above!

Comment: If I answered your question please upvote and ask another question rather than adding more tasks to your original question. You may also reach out to me for work and contracts involving R.